# Using apt dist-update causes invalid gateway to be set

Tags: networking, apt

My home network uses a 172.16.69.0/24 range of IPs and frequently when I do `apt update && apt dist-upgrade` the gateway is set to 192.168.1.1.

I'm having trouble seeing what is causing this change on update.